# ListView change rows

Tags: android, listview

This is my layout for each row of the `ListView`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llRow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llClosed"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

Stuff Inside

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llOpen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

Stuff Inside

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The idea is when I click a `ListView` item it sets the *llClosed* to `Gone` and the *llOpen* to `Visible` so that later with some animation i can create a expanding look.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
                View open = v.findViewById(R.id.llOpen);
                View close = v.findViewById(R.id.llClosed);
                close.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        open.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

The problem is that when i click the first row it changes not only the first but also another, 2 or 3 rows down. What could cause this?

**SOLVED :** If i do llOpen.setVisibility(View.GONE) in the list adapter it will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

well, one problem is you have two linear layout with the same ID `android:id="@+id/llClosed"`

All elements in a layout that have an ID should have a unique one. try `android:id="@+id/llClosed1"` and `android:id="@+id/llClosed2"`

I'm sorry but I can't really tell what you are trying to accomplish, but it does look like you might wanna try the `expandablelistview` class.  Check out:

http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html

http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/04/steps-to-implement-expandablelistview.html

Comment: That as a mistake when copying. The linear layouts have different ids. The idea is then i click a row the llClosed disappears and the llOpen appears. Like expanding row.